# Change the Color Overlay color of multiple layers at once

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style

I have a file with a bunch of layers that I've applied Color Overlay to (Layer > Layer Style > Color Overlay). Right now they are all the same color. I'd like to change them all to a different color (but they will still all be the same color as each other). Is there an easy/quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the color overlay of one layer
- Click this layer with the right mouse button to see the options menu
- Choose > Copy Layer Style
- Select all the other layers holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Win.
- Click any of those layers with the right mouse button to see the options menu
- Choose > Paste Layer Style

Comment: Thank you! One note for future readers: the first line should read "change the color overlay of one layer," not "to one layer."